# Python: Glob only reading one file instead of two

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file, glob

I have two different .txt files. I am trying to read and turn them into a dictionary. I noticed that on the function I have, it only reads one of the files. I thought glob would at least read through all of them.

When I just try to read the files without turning them into a dictionary yet, this code works. It prints out contents from the two .txt files

```
data = ""
for file in glob.glob(".txt"):
    with open(file) as filenames:
        data = data + filenames.read()
return data
```

When I try to read the file using some regex pattern to read certain strings, it only recognizes one of the files. Here are my two files and function:

File1.txt

```
file.py Marvel/GuardiansOfGalaxy 300 1
file.py DC/Batman 504 1
file.py GameOfThrones 900 0
file.py DC/Superman 200 1
file.py Marvel/CaptainAmerica 342 0
```

File2.txt

```
file.py Science/Biology 200 1
file.py Math/Calculus 342 0
file.py Psychology 324 1
file.py Anthropology 234 0
file.py Science/Chemistry 444 1
```

Function:

```
import glob
import re 

def read():
  pattern = re.compile(r"file\.py (.+).*? (\d+) \d+")

  data_files = []
  for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(file, 'r') as filenames:

      data_files = dict(pattern.findall(filenames.read()))

  return data_files

print(read())
```

I need my output to read both of the files and also make the dictionary output start a new line like:

```
'Science/Biology': '200'
'Math/Calculus': '342'
'Psychology': '324'
....
```

I hope my question makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I think your problem is you set `data_files = dict...` instead of `data_files.append(dict...`. This means that each time you read in a new file, you overwrite whatever you read in for the previous file, so you only have the results for a single file at the end (the last file).

Comment: @Nathan That part totally flew over my head. I'm also wondering how I would create a new line from that dictionary to get the format I wanted?